# Git push ignoring blockly subdir

Tags: git, laravel, blockly

I am using Blockly inside a Laravel app (Vagrant homestead vm).

When I add blockly to the /public folder I get a 403 forbidden error. When I move Blockly to /public/js/blockly, everything works fine locally.

However when I git add ., commit and push, the blockly folder is empty on our Github repo.

Does anyone know what's up?
Thanks

Comment: did you checked  `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Laravel .gitignore file does not ignore public. Just realized that blockly git clone has its own .git and .gitignore files. Should I delete .git folder from blockly and try again?

Comment: don't delete the `.git ` folder, you should check if there is any `.gitignore`  file, and inside that, your folders or files are mentioned or not.

Comment: In Laravel my .gitignore is
`
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
/.idea
/.vagrant
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
.env
`

and the .gitignore within blockly
`
node_modules
npm-debug.log
.DS_Store
.settings
.project
*.pyc
*.komodoproject
/nbproject/private/
`

Comment: eg:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.gitignore
https://github.com/google/blockly/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: See inside this, `.gitignore`, its containing files and folder paths that git will ignore.
and inside this, there is two file or folder `/public/hot, /public/storage` 
and i guess in laravel it ignores `/public` folder

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I don't understand why it is ignoring /public/js/blockly/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151590/discussion-between-saikat-chakrabortty-and-dazzle).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mucking around with submodules and editing config files, I deleted the file I downloaded with git clone and downloaded the file manually as a zip and now it appears to be working!